# Autocomplete for vim?

Tags: solidity, vim

I have recently switched from vs-code to vim, and while I really like the workflow I do miss autocomplete. Is there a plug-in anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

There is a great Vim Auto-complete plugin called YouCompleteMe: https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe. It has semantic autocomplete support for several languages (not including solidity), but it also has language-agnostic autocomplete that works quite well in solidity.